# How to avoid using global in C to detect setting of variable?

Tags: c, design-patterns, global

I have function foo() which is called from two different code flows.
Lets say these two code flows have two different functions calling foo()

bar() and tar()

I want to do make some decision on the basis of which function(bar() or tar()) has called foo().
Currently, I am setting global variable IN_BAR = 1; in case of bar() and IN_BAR = 0; in case of tar.
Then I check the value of "IN_BAR" in foo() and do something.

```
int IN_BAR = 0; // global

void bar () {
...
IN_BAR = 1;
foo();
IN_BAR = 0;
..
}

void tar() {
...
foo();
...
}

void foo() {
...
if (IN_BAR)
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
}
```

Currently, there is a lot of places (in codebase) which look like this. I want to avoid using globals and setting & resetting of global variables.
Is there way to handle the above mentioned situation? Or is there a design flaw here?

EDIT:
There are cases when bar() & tar() are not calling foo() directly i.e. there are alot of calls in between, but decision has to be made at bar() & tar().

bar()->*filler1()->filler2()*->foo()
tar()->*func1()->func2()*->foo()

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// globals
int data = 0;
int IN_BAR = 0;

int calculate()
{
    // Some algorithm.
    return 10;
}

void foo()
{
    if (!IN_BAR)
        data = calculate();
    // Use data in this method.
    printf("Data: %d\n", data);
}

// This function is a place holder for multiple functions.
void func_bar()
{
    foo();
}

void bar()
{
    IN_BAR = 1;
    data = calculate();
    func_bar();
    IN_BAR = 0;
}

// This function is a place holder for multiple functions.
void func_tar()
{
    foo();
}

void tar()
{
    func_tar();
}

int main()
{
    int c = 1;
    if (c == 1)
        bar();
    else
        tar();
    return 1;
}
```

I am calculating something inside bar and want to reuse in foo(), but in case of tar I am not calculating and want to calculate again as no calculation is done.

How can I handle this case?

Comment: Is adding a parameter an option?

Comment: Either add a parameter or split the function up into two — `bar_foo()` and `tar_foo()` and do the appropriate work in each, using a common function to do the common work.  (`void bar_foo(void) { common_foo(); do_this();` }` and `void tar_foo(void) { common_foo(); do_that(); }`)  Eschew the global variable; it is a gruesome nightmare.

Comment: Avoiding global variables is traditionally done by introducing extra function parameters.

Comment: There are alot of functions in between the two functions (bar() and foo()), so should I add another parameter to all the functions and update all the callers in the codebase (which is fairly large)? @Yunnosch

Comment: Well my question was whether that would be an option. The one to answer that question is probably you. Or your superior, or software architect, or Product Owner, ... just not me... But if the question is whether adding an additional parameter in only one of the functions in between helps, then the answer is no, that would just return you to the initial problem this question is asking about.

Comment: Consider extending your [mcve], adding one layer of in-between functions, as a  placeholder for the multiple levels of in betweens. (Actually you would probably have to turn your code quotes/pseudo code into an MCVE, then extend it with the placeholder functions...). By the way StackOverflow users love MCVEs, some of them (including me when I am not careful) complain about not seeing one even if the question does not need one. Doing everything to make one, even if not entirely necessary, therefor (unfairly) gets you even better perception... just as a "trick" for the future. ;-)

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. Is it better now? @Yunnosch

Comment: Better, I recommend to change "place holder for multiple functions" to "place holder for multiple levels of function calls, ending at foo()".

Comment: I think it gets clearer now why you implicitly dislike another parameter. I think I would still go that way, which is basically calebs answer. Sigh, I should have made my own answer immediatly, instead of first clarifying your situation and needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there way to handle the above mentioned situation?

It sounds like `foo()` needs some sort of information about the context in which it's running in order to do the right thing. If you think about it that way, then that context, whatever it is, is clearly an input into `foo()`, and so should be passed in as a parameter. In other words, you should call it something like `foo(context)`.

> Or is there a design flaw here?

That depends on the circumstance. A function shouldn't really know or care where it's called from, but perhaps there's some information related to the caller that makes sense as an input. For example, if you know that `bar()` is only called when there's some data available, and `tar()` is only called when data isn't available, then you could pass in a parameter that indicates whether data is available. Or, you could just pass in the data itself if it's available or `nil` if it's not.

The reason a function shouldn't care about who is calling it is that that kind of knowledge makes the function fragile, hard to test, and hard to use. It's fragile because the function might break if the caller's circumstances change. It's hard to test because testing generally involves calling the function, and there's an expectation that the function's behavior will be the same no matter where it's called from. And it's hard to use because you need to know about the function's dependence on the caller: if you ever want to call it from somewhere else, you have to update the function.

> There are cases when bar() & tar() are not calling foo() directly i.e. there are alot of calls in between, but decision has to be made at bar() & tar().

The answer is still pretty much the same: the caller has some information that's an input to the callee, so it should pass it as a parameter. Let's consider your call chain:

> tar()->func1()->func2()->foo()

Since `tar()` calls `func1()` instead of `foo()`, it shouldn't make any assumptions about how `func1()` works — it should just pass in the information that `func1()` needs to do its job and get back the result that `func1()` returns. The "decision" that `tar()` and `bar()` make, whatever that actually is, is according to you a necessary input to `foo()`, and therefore it's a necessary input to `func2()`, and therefore it's a necessary input to `func1()`, even if `func1()` and `func2()` don't use that information other than to call some other function. So, one option is to have the intermediate functions each take a new parameter that they just pass along to the next function in the chain.

Another option which might work better if there could be more than one "decision" that affect `foo()`, is to create some sort of structure that provides "context" or "environment" information, and have the intermediate functions each pass that along. You see that style a lot in graphics systems, where there's a drawing context with a large number of parameters that can changed, and that context is a parameter passed to most of the functions in the system.

The problem you're facing is the procedural version of the "how do I get the data I need" problem that often comes up in object oriented programming. The choices are either: 1) have the object make an assumption about where to get the data it needs; or 2) tell the object where to get the data it needs. Option 1 typically involves a singleton or other globally-accessible chunk of data. Option 2 is known as *dependency injection* and is often summarized as "tell, don't ask."

Another solution that you might not have considered is to break `foo()` up into two or more functions, so that `tar()` and `bar()` end up calling two different functions that each do the right thing for their situation. That could work if the call chains for `tar()` and `bar()` really are distinct. In this case, you're still essentially passing the same information — you're just doing it implicitly using the function name.

Let's try to make this advice more concrete by looking at the code you provided:

```
void foo()
{
    if (!IN_BAR)
        data = calculate();
    // Use data in this method.
    printf("Data: %d\n", data);
}
```

The reason that `foo()` here depends on `IN_BAR` is that `bar()` calls `calculate()` and stores the result in `data`, which is another global variable. If `foo()` is invoked as part of `tar()`, then `calculate()` hasn't been called and `data` presumably won't have a useful value, so you need to call it inside `foo()` in that case.

Your specific question seems to be about ways to avoid the need for `IN_BAR`, so let's look at that first. One solution here is to just make a valid `data` a requirement for calling `foo()`. If you do that, then `foo()` doesn't need `IN_BAR` -- it can just assume that `data` is always valid, because calling it without that is an error. It moves the responsibility for calling `calculate()` out of `foo()`'s realm, and it lets you call `calculate()` anywhere higher up the chain -- you could do it in `tar()` or in `func_tar()` or anywhere else, as long as you do it prior to calling `foo()`, and `foo()` becomes simpler:

```
void foo()
{
    // Use data in this method.
    printf("Data: %d\n", data);
}
```

If there's some reason that you can't do that, then you can at least tie the validity of `data` to that one variable. You could do that either by defining some value for `data` that means "invalid", so that you can *just* look at data and know whether or not it's valid. For example, you could change it's type to `int*` and initialize it to `nil`, and then have `calculate()` return a pointer to the `int` that it calculates:

```
void foo()
{
    if (data == nil)
        data = calculate();
    // Use data in this method.
    printf("Data: %d\n", data);
}
```

It would be much better, though, to reimplement `foo()` so that `data` is passed in explicitly:

```
void foo(int data)
{
    // Use data in this method.
    printf("Data: %d\n", data);
}
```

Now you don't need either `data` or `IN_BAR` as globals, and `foo()`'s need for a value for `data` is explicit. If it's okay for `foo()` to call `calculate()` itself when there's no `data` value, the surely it must be OK for `func_tar()` to call `calculate()` immediately before calling `foo()`:

```
void func_tar()
{
    foo( calculate() );
}
```

In the case of `bar()`, which calls `calculate()` itself, you've already got a `data` value, and that should be passed along to it's subsidiary functions:

```
void func_bar(int data)
{
    foo(data);
}
```

That's true even if `func_bar()` is a stand-in for several functions. **The bottom line is that using a global variable to avoid passing `data` information in parameters is a bad idea.** Perhaps `data` is also a stand-in for several different values; in that case, combine them all into a single structure as I described in the discussion above.

Comment: Thanks Caleb! That's a good way of thinking about function and their expected behavior. I'll try to refactor the functions in order to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: BTW, I have updated the question. If you could take a look again. Thanks!

Comment: @Deeps I've added examples based on your example code.

Comment: Wow! That is some great explanation and in depth solution. I have taken your suggestion and broke the foo() into two parts and called each version from two code flows, which made it easy to pass info to each version correctly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid this, then *don't* have `bar` call `foo`. Since obviously `bar` knows about `foo`, it can call the appropriate version and leave that decission to the caller.

Create a separate function for the case of `bar` calls `foo` and for `tar` calling `foo`:

```
void bar () {
    ...
    foobar();
    ..
}

void tar() {
    ...
    footar();
    ...
}

void foobar() {
    ...
    do_this();
}
void footar() {
    ...
    do_that();
}
```

---

Edit:

To avoid having to make many code changes, you can change only where currently the global variable is used (and added Jonathan Leffler's suggestion):

```
void bar () {
    ...
    foobar(); // change only here
    ..
}

void tar() {
    ...
    foo();
    ...
}

void foobar() {
    foocommon();
    do_this();
}
void foo() {
    foocommon();
    do_that();
}
void foocommon()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The common bit in `foobar()` and `footar()` (represented by `...`) shouldn't be repeated; you could add a `foocommon()` function that is called by `foobar()` and `footar()`.  It's fairly easy while all the functions take zero parameters.  (I'd prefer to see the functions defined with `(void)` instead of `()` too.)

Comment: Thanks Paul! I'll check if I can use this method to make changes. Meanwhile, I have updated the question to reflect my current situation. Please refer to the "Edit" section. Thanks for you response.

Comment: If you have a chain of functions eventually calling `foo`, then you need to pass the context as a parameter. As in many cases you need to refactor the code anyway, you might want to do a (partial) redesign.